# Can a car charger circuit be branched from a cooker circuit?

Tags: wiring

I would like to get an EV charger installed on the outside wall of the house but the consumer unit on my house (a new build) is in a cupboard in the middle of the house i.e. it's not on an outside wall.

From what I've read the EV charger requires a 32amp cable to be installed but this will be difficult because of where the consumer unit is located.  Could the installer tap into an existing 32amp cable for the cooker?  As it happens the kitchen is the otherside of the wall I want the charger mounted on so I wondered if they could take a feed from the cooker wire and run that through the wall to the point where the charger would ideally be located.

Comment: A good electrician will not “tap” into the cooker feed for the simple reason that both could be on at the same time.

Comment: Sure you could, just change to a gas cooker.

Comment: What do you mean by "consumer unit" ?   Is that the breaker panel or just a hi-current (or hi-voltage) outlet?

Comment: I'm sure the manufacturer of whatever charging station you're buying (Tesla?  Chargepoint?  etc) has a very specific set of instructions as to wire gauge, voltages & phases, and so on required.  Use them.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "consumer unit" is the UK term for breaker panel.  It replaced "fuse box" when fuses went out of fashion (which wasn't that long ago in this country).

Comment: I want it done right and I'm not looking to cut corners. My concern was there is no easy way to get a cable from the consumer unit (breaker panel) as it is inside an internal cupboard in my house. This would involve ugly trunking or routing under floors which would be both costly and difficult.

Answer (score 6):

No, you do not want to "tap into" an existing circuit like this.  The EV charger is going to draw near maximum current during its entire charging interval and I'm sure it requires a dedicated circuit just like your stove/range/oven (whatever that is) on the other side of the wall.

Yes, you'll need an electrician to run an appropriately size new wire from your circuit panel/consumer unit to the place where you plan to install the EV charger.  Yes, that will incur some cost but I'm sure you want an effective and SAFE EV charging installation not some half-baked installation that may not work properly and may be a hazard.

Do it properly or don't do it at all.  The cost to install this correctly is likely going to be small compared to what you spent on the EV to begin with.

Comment: I agree you don't want to damage the car, but (1) as new car prices go, sadly that's not a big number in the USA;  (2) EVs have extensive input protection circuitry, and I can't envision any household-sourced voltage causing a problem.

Comment: @jwh20 in Norway, there's chargers that comes with power monitoring equipment to be mounted in the switchboard, so that it'll reduce charging current to stay under total consumption limits. That allows sharing. In many cases, EV is plugged in for far longer than needed charging time, so temporary restrictions is not a big problem.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Electrician can run dedicated new cable from outside meter box which is a straight run and only 3 meters away. Will install small consumer unit in meter box cupboard.

Comment: Good to hear, but this doesn't answer the question you posed. You should probably accept jwh20's answer. Take the [tour] if I'm speaking Greek.